# Chrome Extension not working (Error with permissions?)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions, rss

Thanks for taking the time to read this.
Here is the directory of my extension folder.

And here is the manifest code :

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Technobuffalo Stories",
  "description": "Your Description about Extension goes here",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "popup.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://feeds.feedburner.com/*" ]
   } ],
  "permissions": [ "http://feeds.feedburner.com/*" ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon_16.jpeg",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Here is popup.html :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Technobuffalo Stories
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
    <div id="feed" style="background-color:orange;height:500px;width:500px;" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and last of all here is popup.js :

google.load("feeds", "1");

```
function initialize() {
  var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://feeds.feedburner.com/technobuffalo/rss?format=xml");
  feed.load(function(result) {
    if (!result.error) {
      var container = document.getElementById("feed");
      for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title));
        container.appendChild(div);
      }
    }
  });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

When I open the popup.html file as it is, the required result is displayed but when I load the Chrome extension, only the background color of the div can be seen. Is there any problem with the permissions that I have set or is it something else?

Thanks,
Yash.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the following line to *manifest.json* to be able to use resources from *www.google.com*:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com; object-src 'self'"
```

As Rob W already pointed out this is a security feature that has been introduced with manifest version 2.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer my question!